# Is it possible to change the url pathnames for images stored in an AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm saving images uploaded by users into an aws s3 bucket, and when they're saved they have a url that looks like this `https://<S3-BUCKET-NAME>.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/<SOME-RANDOM-ID>.png`.

Is there a way I can change this url so it looks like `https://<MY-WEBSITE-DOMAIN>/image/<SOME-RANDOM-ID>` instead?

Answer (score 2):

These URLs are public, means they can be accessed from the public internet.

If you want your users to access them through a different URL then you need a domain and route from that domain to S3. For example: `https://my-domain.com/image.png` routes to `https://.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/image.png`

Route53 supports this, take a look to [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html) on how to route from R53 to S3.

Comment: One thing to mention... the bucket name will need to match the DNS name. So, if your domain is `example.com`, then the bucket will also need to be named `example.com`. You then configure Route 53 with a `CNAME` record to point the domain to Amazon S3.